# Writing a Regex pattern c++

Tags: c++, regex, string

I need help completing this regex pattern.

Here is the full string:

```
INSERT((1574,"Greene County, Missouri",mo,50,29,77,05000US29077,285449),geography)
```

Here is the portion of the string I am trying to search for using regex_search:

```
(1574,"Greene County, Missouri",mo,50,29,77,05000US29077,285449)
```

Here is my regex pattern and code:

```
regex pattern2("\\(|[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]|\,|\"|");
regex_search (substring,matcher,pattern2);
   for(auto x:matcher)
   {
     substring1 = matcher.suffix().str();
     cout << substring1 << endl;
   }
```

substring will output:

```
1574,"Greene County, Missouri",mo,50,29,77,05000US29077,285449),geography)
```

So not what I need. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: There is no the escape sequence `\,`, probably you wanted `\\,`. I suggest using raw string literals: `regex pattern2(R"(\(|[0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]|\,|"|)");`

Answer (score 0):

To match `(1574,"Greene County, Missouri",mo,50,29,77,05000US29077,285449)` you can use a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
[^*()\r\n]+\((\([^()\r\n]+\))[^()\r\n]+\)
```

In parts

- `[^*()\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except the listed
- `\(` Match first opening parenthesis
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match second opening parenthesis

    - `[^()\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except the listed
  - `\)` Close second opening parenthesis
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^()\r\n]+`
- `\)` Close first opening parenthesis

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pe0tBQ/1)

You could also make the pattern more restrict by using repeating non capturing groups and use the allowed characters from the character classes that you intended to use:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(\(((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+|"[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,? [a-zA-Z0-9]+)+")(?:,(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+|"[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:,? [a-zA-Z0-9]+)+"))+)\),[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zoFKx5/1)